# Can I store sensitive data in a Vert.x context in a Quarkus application?

Tags: quarkus, vert.x

I am looking for a place to store some request scoped attributes such as user id using a Quarkus request filter. I later want to retrieve these attributes in a Log handler and put them in the MDC logging context.

Is `Vertx.currentContext()` the right place to put such request attributes? Or can the properties I set on this context be read by other requests?

If this is not the right place to store such data, where would be the right place?

Comment: Not sure about Quarkus, but in vert.x I'd use the `RequestContect` to store request scoped attributes

Comment: Take a look at https://reactiverse.io/reactiverse-contextual-logging/. It leverages `Context.putLocal`/`Context.getLocal` to achieve MDC-style logging in Vert.x. I do not know what wrinkles, if any, quarkus brings.

Comment: See my response, do not use putLocal or getLocal blindly, as it may leak between unrelated processing. In Quarkus 2.7.2, we check for you.

Comment: @dano I ended up using `ContextualData.get` and `ContextualData.put` from this source. Apparently they have written this nice helper Class that integrates into Vert.x and what achieves exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes ... and no :-D
`Vertx.currentContext()` can provide two type of objects:

- root context shared between all the concurrent processing executed on this event loop (so do NOT share data)
- duplicated contexts, which are local to the processing and its continuation (you can share in these)

In Quarkus 2.7.2, we have done a lot of work to improve our support of duplicated context. While before, they were only used for HTTP, they are now used for gRPC and @ConsumeEvent. Support for Kafka and AMQP is coming in Quarkus 2.8.

Also, in Quarkus 2.7.2, we introduced two new features that could be useful:

1. you cannot store data in a root context. We detect that for you and throw an UnsupportedOperationException. The reason is safety.
2. we introduced a new utility class ( `io.smallrye.common.vertx.ContextLocals` to access the *context locals*.

Here is a simple example:

```java
 AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
public Uni<String> invoke() {
    Context context = Vertx.currentContext();

    ContextLocals.put("message", "hello");
    ContextLocals.put("id", counter.incrementAndGet());       

    return invokeRemoteService()
       // Switch back to our duplicated context:
        .emitOn(runnable -> context.runOnContext(runnable))
        .map(res -> {
            // Can still access the context local data
            String msg = ContextLocals.<String>get("message").orElseThrow();
            Integer id = ContextLocals.<Integer>get("id").orElseThrow();
            return "%s - %s - %d".formatted(res, msg, id);
        });
}
```

Comment: How do you duplicate the context? Is sth. missing there?

Comment: Most of the time Quarkus will execute you on a duplicated context. We are adding the last few  part that do not execute your code on duplicated contexts.